# Akka testkit expecting two messages in any order

Tags: scala, akka

Akka TestKit expectation methods assert the order of messages received. In my test, I expect the `TestProbe` to receive two messages. But the order is not important. Both message expectations need to use the partial function variant.

This is what I have so far. It passes, but it has awful duplication and would allow false positives (if one of the messages arrives twice).

```
payRepoProbe.expectMsgPF(3.seconds) {
  case UpdateStatus(List(_), Failed, Some("PaymentUnderfunded")) => ()
  case UpdateStatus(ps, Succeeded, None) if ps.size == 4 => ()
}
payRepoProbe.expectMsgPF(3.seconds) {
  case UpdateStatus(List(_), Failed, Some("PaymentUnderfunded")) => ()
  case UpdateStatus(ps, Succeeded, None) if ps.size == 4 => ()
}
```

How should I write this assertion instead?

Comment: What is the spec you are using flat specLike or asyncSpecLike? Could you all your whole spec file because it’s not sufficient as far as I know to answer this question.

Comment: This is the spec: https://github.com/0rora/0rora/blob/23a88d4e28c5a71b598a60a33090280d3db979a8/test/actors/PaymentControllerSpec.scala#L167-L203